# Can not retrieve the id of a foreign key [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables: User and demands. A User can have as many demands as he wants. Inside the demands table, there is the User foreign key.

When the User completes the form, I put the User & demands information inside those 2 tables.

But I do not know how to have the User id to put it inside the demands table.

Here is the function inside my Controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        $demand = new Demand;
        $user = new user ;
        $user ->numStudent= $request->NumStudent;
        $user ->role_id = "3";
        $user ->Lastname = $request->LastName;
        $user ->FirstName= $request->FirstName;
        $user ->numero_etudiant = "12345678";
        $user ->email = $request->Email;     
        $user ->password = bcrypt('idk');
        $user ->adress= $request->Adress;
        $user ->phone = $request->Phone;
        $user ->parcours = $request->Parcours;

        $demand->status_id= "3";
        //problem below
        $demand->User_id= $User;
        //
        $demand->time_id = $request->LoanTime;
        $demand->creation_date = $request->CreationDate;
        $demand->comments = "";

        $user ->save();
        $demand->save();

        return redirect('/demands_list');

    }
```

But it says "Can't use method return value in write context".

Cordially

Comment: Sidenote, you case is all over the place... `new user` should be `new User()`, `NumStudent` should be `num_student` (same with `last_name`, `first_name`, `loan_time`, `creation_date` and `user_id`), `Email`, `Address`, `Phone` and `Parcours` should be lowercase, no space between `$user` and `->`...

Comment: Does the 'redirect' function actually return something? If not, you shouldn't return the call.

Comment: @RomiHalasz Yes, it does; it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse`, which Laravel uses to properly handle HTTP redirects to the supplied route/url. If you don't include `return`, it won't redirect :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm french so I wrote everything in french and I change the words without consideration. But my original code is like you said ;) thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save first the instance of your user before using its properties. Your code should look like this.

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $demand = new Demand;
        $user = new user ;
        $user->numStudent= $request->NumStudent;
        $user->role_id = "3";
        $user->Lastname = $request->LastName;
        $user->FirstName= $request->FirstName;
        $user->numero_etudiant = "12345678";
        $user->email = $request->Email;     
        $user->password = bcrypt('idk');
        $user->adress= $request->Adress;
        $user->phone = $request->Phone;
        $user->parcours = $request->Parcours;
        $user->save();

        $demand->status_id= "3";
        //problem below
        $demand->User_id= $user->id;
        //
        $demand->time_id = $request->LoanTime;
        $demand->creation_date = $request->CreationDate;
        $demand->comments = "";


        $demand->save();

        return redirect('/demands_list');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by your tags that you are looking for an *Eloquent* (i.e. Laravel) way of doing this.

The short answer: use **[route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding)** and keep your controller methods organized and single-focused.

As already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60285151/4468423), your `User` needs to be saved first.  I would recommend you do this step in its own controller:

```php
// UsersController.php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $attributes = $request->validate([
       // validation rules
    ]);

    $user = User::create($attributes);

    return redirect('/users/' . $user->id);
}
```

Now that you have a `User` created, you can then attach related models.  Create a separate set of routes pointing to a separate controller for handling the relationship:

```php
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/user/{user}/demands', 'UserDemandsController@index');
Route::post('/user/{user}/demands', 'UserDemandsController@store');
//                 ^^^^^^
//       used with route model binding
```

Here's where **route model binding** comes into play, loading the model straight from the route parameters (`{user}`):

```php
// UserDemandsController.php
public function store(Request $request, User $user) {  // <-- ROUTE MODEL BINDING
    $attributes = $request->validate([
       // validation rules
    ]);

    $user->demands()->create($attributes);
}
```

The result is very clean, simple code.

Comment: Thanks. The validation rules are " $utilisateur->role_id = "3";" and so on ?

Comment: @Balaure no, validation is where you make sure the user enters valid information. (e.g. country should not be a number, etc). see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)